# Express file upload using multer file is undefined always

Tags: express, post, file-upload, multer

I have tried to make an api to upload files in express using multer middleware but the request.file is undefined.

the express code is given below,

```
const express = require("express");
var multer = require('multer');
const cors = require("cors");

var app = express();

app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

const multerMid = multer({
  storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
  limits: {
    fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024,
  },
});

app.post('/saveFile', multerMid.single('dp'), (request,response)=>{
  try{
    var dp = request.file;
    if(dp)
    {
      return response.send("file uploaded");
    }
    else{
      return response.send("No file uploaded");
    }
  }catch(error)
  {
    return response.send(error.errorMessage);
  }
});
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

> **No file uploaded**

this is what I always receive when I post a file to the route using the following html.

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action = "<server>/saveFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="dp"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Save">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to upload the file to file to firebase storage thats why I don't use a static storage location in the multer object,

I am stuck please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here a middleware needs to be defined

```
app.post('/saveFile', multerMiddleWare, (request,response)=>{...});

const multerMiddleWare = (req, res, next) => {
  multerMid(req, res,
      (error) => {
        if (!error) return next();
        return next('error');
      });
};


const multerMid = multer({
  storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
  limits: {
    fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024,
  },
}).single('dp');
```